# Reload document with previous post request

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do i reload the page with the same ajax request as previous with button click? I am using Post ajax request. I used the following code to reload the page but i want to post same data as previous with the button click.

```
<input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that with a location.reload(). Y don't you just do another Ajax post on click?

EDIT:
for example, if you are using jQuery.post() (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to do your AJAX posts, then whatever you sent as the 'data' should still be available right?

So, using that same data you can do another post.
e.g. (again in JQuery)

```
$('input[type='button']').live('click', function(){
  $.post(<url>, 
     data,
      ....
   );
});
```

Comment: How to make another Ajax post with the same data posted as before?